# Unknown symbol in ERD

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I was searching for the meaning of the symbol marked in red in the image below, but I didn't get anything.

So, do you guys know what it means?

[image: What are those?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indicates a supertype/subtype relationship. The notation is used in Microsoft Visio, where it's called a category. A double horizontal line is used to indicate a complete category.

In your image, `Jurusan` records information about the parent/supertype while `Animasi`, `TKJ`, `RPL` and `Otomotif` describe children/subtypes.

Here's a video on the topic.

[Supertype/subtype hierarchies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCvAa5wh5lg)

Comment: How do you create this notation in Draw.io?

Answer (score 1):

It does seem to represent supertypes and subtypes. Often the circle will have either a **d** or an **o** inside. The **d** stands for "disjoint" or non-overlapping and the **o** would stand for "overlapping". These would be constraints. A **d** would mean that an instance can only appear in one subtype. An **o** would imply that an instance can be in multiple subtypes. In your example, I'm assuming the supertype instance in question would come from your **Colon Siswa** table.

Since no information is included in the circle, we do not know. As for the line beneath the circle, there is an option of **1 line - partial completeness** or **2 lines - total completeness**. The completeness constraint identifies whether an instance in the supertype has to be in one of the subtypes. A single line implies that a supertype instance **does not** have to be in the subtype. While a double line (2 lines), implies that an instance **HAS** to be in the subtype.

Supertypes and subtypes are sometimes organized in a specialization hierarchy. The ER model is sometimes called an "enhanced" or "extended" ER Model or EER in that case.

The model you provided is also missing the **subtype discriminator**. The subtype discriminator would let us know which attribute (field) determines which subtype the instance would belong too. Since you're familiar with the language your model was created in, it may be obvious how it will be determined which instances from the supertype (parent entity) would fall into which subtypes (child entities).

We sometimes call the relationships shown on a specialization hierarchy a "is a" relationship.

You can find examples of these relationships in the textbook below:

Coronel, C. (2017). Database Systems: Design, Implementation, & Management, 12th Edition. [VitalSource Bookshelf Online]. Retrieved from https://bookshelf.vitalsource.com/#/books/9781337509596/

or the following reading room...not my own, but it is an example from the text above.

[Reading Room Notes](http://www.myreadingroom.co.in/notes-and-studymaterial/65-dbms/490-specialization-hierarchy.html)

Answer (score 0):

cardinality symbol, i think `one to many` symbol